# chart.js unreadable X axis

Tags: chart.js

I'm working on my project, where I'm using chart.js charts, but I came across the problem that I don't know how to solve. X axis consist dates which are not sequentially, and my chart is unreadable now.
[image]
My chart code:

```js
var dragOptions = {
  animationDuration: 1000
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("weightChart");
var weightChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      lineTension: 0.3,
      lineColor: "yellow",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 222, 124, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 222, 124, 1)",
      pointRadius: 0,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm, dd.MM.yyyy',
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value
          }
        },
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          source: 'auto',
          padding: 5,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value + ' kg';
          }
        },
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
        }
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        limits: {
          x: {
            min: 'original',
            max: 'original'
          },
          y: {
            min: 'original',
            max: 'original'
          },
        },
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          pinch: {
            enabled: true
          },
          mode: 'xy',
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  }
});

time = ["20:43:09", "20:27:59", "20:12:49", "17:21:32", "17:06:22", "16:51:12", "16:36:02", "16:20:52", "16:05:42", "15:50:34", "15:35:22", "15:20:13", "15:05:03", "14:49:53", "14:34:43", "14:19:34", "14:04:23", "13:49:14", "13:34:04", "13:33:24", "13:32:29", "13:31:53", "13:31:47", "13:28:43", "13:13:33", "12:55:14", "12:52:35", "18:09:57", "18:34:19", "18:34:05", "18:33:27", "18:33:02", "18:32:37", "18:32:15", "18:31:47", "18:31:21", "18:31:02", "18:29:55", "18:29:33", "16:45:09", "19:03:50", "16:26:49", "16:14:40", "16:02:31", "15:50:23", "15:38:14", "15:26:05", "15:13:56", "15:01:48", "14:49:39", "14:37:30", "14:25:22", "13:54:44", "13:44:49", "13:32:40", "13:14:46", "13:14:46", "13:09:48", "13:09:48", "16:10:07", "15:57:58", "15:45:50", "15:43:07", "15:41:44", "15:40:32", "15:40:05", "15:33:35", "15:17:51", "15:16:46", "15:15:42", "15:14:38", "15:13:33", "15:12:29", "15:11:25", "15:10:20", "15:09:16", "15:08:12", "15:07:07", "15:06:03", "15:04:59", "15:03:55", "15:02:50", "15:01:46", "15:00:42", "14:59:37", "14:58:33", "14:57:29", "14:56:24", "14:56:00", "14:54:56", "14:53:52", "14:52:47", "14:51:43", "14:50:39", "14:49:34", "14:48:30", "14:47:26", "14:46:21", "14:45:17", "14:44:13", "14:43:08", "14:42:04", "14:41:00", "14:39:55", "14:38:51", "14:37:47", "14:36:42", "16:49:10", "16:48:06", "16:47:02", "16:45:57", "16:44:53", "16:43:49", "16:42:44", "16:41:40", "16:40:36", "16:39:31", "16:38:27", "16:37:23", "16:37:23", "16:37:11", "16:37:10", "16:36:07", "16:36:06", "16:35:02", "16:35:02", "16:34:00", "16:33:57", "16:32:53", "16:31:49", "16:30:45", "16:30:44", "16:29:43", "16:29:40", "16:28:50", "16:26:12", "16:25:07", "16:24:03", "16:24:03", "16:22:59", "16:22:59", "16:21:55", "16:21:55", "16:21:27", "16:21:26", "16:20:22", "16:20:22", "16:19:21", "16:19:20", "16:18:29", "16:18:28", "16:17:36", "16:17:36", "16:16:44", "16:16:44", "16:15:52", "16:15:52", "16:15:00", "16:14:59", "16:14:08", "16:14:07", "16:13:15", "16:13:15", "16:12:03", "16:12:03", "16:11:11", "16:11:11", "16:07:43", "16:07:42", "16:07:27", "16:07:26", "16:07:11", "16:07:11", "16:06:55", "16:06:55", "16:06:40", "16:06:39", "16:04:50", "16:04:50", "16:02:44", "16:02:43", "16:02:24", "16:02:24", "16:02:11", "16:02:10", "16:02:00", "16:01:59", "16:00:29", "16:00:29", "15:57:06", "15:57:05", "15:56:57", "15:56:57", "15:56:41", "15:56:41", "15:56:26", "15:56:26", "15:55:01", "15:55:00", "15:54:28", "15:54:27", "15:53:51", "15:53:50", "15:53:43", "15:53:42", "15:53:19", "15:53:18", "15:53:13", "15:53:12", "15:41:41", "15:41:29", "15:32:04", "15:30:33", "15:30:09", "15:29:50", "13:01:13", "13:00:39", "19:02:46", "16:03:00", "15:51:51", "15:51:45", "15:48:20", "15:48:11", "15:38:46", "15:37:50", "15:37:03", "15:36:28", "15:35:27", "15:34:40", "15:34:31", "15:34:24", "15:34:15", "15:31:51", "15:21:53", "15:21:45", "15:21:17", "15:21:10", "15:17:24", "15:16:02", "15:14:44", "15:13:25", "15:13:11", "15:08:23", "15:08:04", "15:06:21", "15:06:03", "15:05:53", "15:04:58", "15:03:47", "15:03:08", "15:01:51", "15:01:41", "15:01:08", "15:00:42", "15:00:29", "15:00:04", "14:59:51", "14:59:44", "14:59:30", "14:57:01", "14:56:49", "14:56:00", "14:55:44", "14:55:40", "15:24:09", "15:23:06", "19:16:11", "19:15:57", "19:13:37", "19:13:34", "19:12:48", "19:12:35", "19:02:28", "19:01:43", "19:01:00", "19:00:49", "19:00:23", "19:00:00", "18:57:11", "18:54:52", "18:53:13", "18:52:29", "18:41:57", "18:41:22", "18:41:07", "18:27:10", "18:25:47", "18:24:02", "18:23:22", "18:23:07", "18:23:00", "18:22:01", "18:21:29", "15:57:05", "15:56:51", "15:56:40", "15:51:46", "15:51:32", "15:48:12", "15:47:59", "15:47:44", "15:47:29", "15:41:58", "15:26:55", "04:17:09", "04:02:09", "03:47:09", "03:32:09", "03:17:09", "03:02:09", "02:47:09", "02:32:09", "02:17:08", "02:02:08", "01:47:09", "01:32:08", "01:17:08", "01:02:08", "00:47:08", "00:32:08", "00:17:09", "00:02:08", "23:47:07", "23:32:07", "23:17:08", "23:02:07", "22:47:06", "22:32:06", "22:17:07", "22:02:07", "21:47:06", "21:32:06", "21:17:06", "21:02:06", "20:47:06", "20:32:05", "20:17:06", "20:02:05", "19:47:04", "19:32:05", "19:17:06", "19:02:05", "18:47:05", "18:32:05", "18:17:05", "18:02:04", "17:47:04", "17:32:04", "17:17:04", "17:02:04", "16:47:03", "16:32:03", "16:17:05", "16:02:04", "15:47:05", "15:32:05", "15:17:05", "15:02:04", "14:47:04", "14:32:04", "14:17:04", "14:02:04", "13:47:04", "13:32:04", "13:17:06", "13:02:04", "12:47:07", "12:46:55", "12:46:17", "12:45:13", "12:45:01", "12:44:45", "12:44:36", "12:42:42", "14:12:27", "14:12:08", "14:11:53", "14:11:39", "14:11:25", "14:11:10", "14:10:56", "14:10:42", "14:10:27", "14:10:13", "14:09:59", "14:09:45", "13:46:38", "16:08:12", "15:46:58", "15:46:49", "15:46:30", "15:46:10", "15:46:01", "15:45:41", "15:45:21", "15:44:43", "15:44:23", "15:44:03", "15:43:43", "15:43:24", "19:43:52", "19:43:32", "19:43:11", "19:42:51", "19:42:31", "19:42:11", "19:41:51", "19:41:31", "19:41:10", "19:40:50", "19:40:30", "19:40:10", "19:39:50", "19:39:30", "19:39:10", "19:38:50", "19:38:30", "19:38:10", "19:37:50", "19:37:31", "19:37:10", "19:36:49", "19:36:38", "19:36:18", "19:35:58", "19:35:38", "19:35:18", "19:34:58", "19:34:38", "19:27:21", "19:27:01", "19:26:41", "19:26:22", "19:26:01", "19:25:41", "19:25:21", "19:25:02", "19:24:42", "19:24:23", "19:24:02", "19:23:42", "19:23:22", "19:23:03", "19:22:42", "19:22:22", "19:22:02", "19:21:42", "19:21:22", "19:21:02", "19:19:40", "19:19:20", "19:19:01", "19:18:40", "19:18:20", "19:18:00", "19:17:40", "19:17:20", "19:17:00", "19:16:41", "19:16:21", "19:16:01", "19:15:22", "19:15:03", "19:14:43", "19:14:34", "19:14:24", "19:12:29", "19:12:24", "19:12:04", "19:11:54", "19:11:37", "19:11:14", "19:10:54", "19:10:34", "19:10:14", "19:09:54", "19:09:34", "19:09:14", "19:08:54", "19:08:34", "19:08:14", "19:07:54", "19:07:34", "19:07:14", "19:06:54", "19:06:34", "19:06:14", "19:06:00", "13:35:06", "13:34:46", "13:33:49", "13:23:34", "13:23:14", "13:22:54", "13:21:36", "13:21:16", "13:20:56", "13:20:36", "13:20:22", "13:20:18", "13:19:58", "13:19:38", "12:46:03", "12:45:54", "12:45:33", "12:45:19", "12:44:59", "12:44:39", "12:44:20", "12:43:59", "12:43:54", "12:43:34", "12:43:14", "12:42:53", "12:42:33", "12:42:13", "12:41:53", "12:41:33", "12:41:13", "12:40:53", "12:40:33", "12:40:13", "12:39:54", "12:39:50", "12:39:30", "12:39:10", "12:39:05", "12:38:42", "12:38:22", "12:37:59", "13:08:31", "13:08:10", "13:07:52", "13:07:32", "13:07:12", "13:06:51", "13:06:31", "13:06:10", "13:05:37", "13:05:17", "13:04:57", "13:04:37", "13:04:17", "13:03:59", "13:03:37", "13:03:17", "13:02:58", "13:02:38", "13:02:18", "13:01:58", "13:01:38", "13:01:18", "13:00:58", "13:00:38", "13:00:18", "12:59:59", "12:59:39", "12:59:19", "12:58:59", "12:58:39", "12:58:19", "12:57:59", "12:57:39", "12:57:19", "12:57:00", "12:56:40", "12:56:21", "12:56:00", "12:55:40", "12:55:20", "12:55:00"]
date = ["2021-11-29", "2021-11-29", "2021-11-29", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-22", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-14", "2021-11-06", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-05", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-04", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-14", "2021-10-14", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-03", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-06", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-03", "2021-07-09", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-08"]
weight = [-1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, 11.33, -1.62, -1.57, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.59, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.61, -1.61, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.59, -1.59, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.57, -1.56, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.59, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.59, -1.59, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.59, -1.59, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.5, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.5, -1.5, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.49, -1.5, -1.5, -1.49, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.51, -1.51, -1.51, -1.51, -1.61, -1.61, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.55, -1.55, -1.56, -1.56, -1.55, -1.55, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.55, -1.55, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.55, -1.54, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.57, -1.57, -1.56, -1.56, -1.56, -1.29, -1.29, -1.34, -2.55, -0.86, -0.87, -1.1, -0.79, -0.83, -0.94, -1.02, -0.79, -0.84, -1.35, -1.39, -1.43, -1.44, -1.23, -0.76, -0.77, -0.76, -0.76, -0.75, -0.68, -1.49, -0.82, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.76, -0.74, -0.74, -0.74, -0.57, -0.57, 0.13, 0.08, -0.66, -0.68, -0.65, -0.33, -1.17, -0.92, -1.61, -0.43, -0.69, -0.68, -0.66, -0.66, -0.63, -0.63, -0.62, 0.31, 1.08, -0.62, -0.7, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.59, -1.59, -1.59, -1.59, -1.6, -1.6, -1.61, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.57, -1.57, -1.58, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.61, -1.62, 0.05, 0.11, 0.16, 0.15, 0.22, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.19, -0.02, -0.01, 0.22, 0.87, 0.78, 0.61, 0.14, 0.12, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.09, 0.11, 0.16, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.13, 0.11, 0.09, 0.07, 0.1, 0.11, 0.14, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.13, 0.14, 0.25, 0.23, 0.22, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.25, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.22, 0.21, 0.17, -0.13, -0.23, -0.38, -0.16, -0.31, -0.3, -0.25, -0.32, -0.35, -0.32, -0.34, -0.34, -0.46, -0.29, -0.3, -0.24, -0.28, 0.03, 0.09, 0.18, 0.19, 0.1, 0.16, 0.16, 0.17, 0.15, 0.16, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16, 0.14, 0.13, 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18]

size = weight.length;
for (var i = -size + 1; i < 0; i++) {

  d = date[-i] + ' ' + time[-i];
  weightChart.data.labels.push(d)
  weightChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(weight[-i]);
  });
}

weightChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@1.2.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <canvas id="weightChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? Or make it readable somehow.

[Edit] I managed to create snippet, I didn't want to share my data because it's large and it takes most lines in code. I hope now you can help me.

Comment: Please share your data. Create a [mre]!

Comment: Cant reproduce it easily with your supplied config so please add a reproducable example

Comment: I made little edit with snippet and data